Custom cascade delete stored procedure for temporal tables in SQL Server
Preface:
I want to create a stored procedure in SQL Server (2016 - v13.0) to manually perform cascading deletes across tables with foreign key constraints, including self-referencing tables. I require a custom implementation due to the use of temporal tables, which do not support cascading deletes. I find this limitation very frustrating, especially given that temporal tables are designed to track deletions. In order to delete a row, it is necessary first to delete all rows that depend on it.
I should be clear: I do not want to touch data in history tables, I only care about deleting rows in the current tables.
My knowledge of SQL isn't very deep, and I'm not sure if this is the best approach. I've considered using soft deletes, but I'm not fond of them due to the clutter they introduce and the need to be diligent in maintaining data accuracy. I've heard of others suggesting a stored procedure for performing deletions explicitly, but in my scenario I have far too many tables to implement a deletion procedure for each individually; instead, I need a dynamic one that will work for any given table row.
Objective:
The stored procedure should:

Accept three parameters: @SchemaName (schema name), @TableName (table name), and @Id (primary key of the entity to delete).
Delete the specified row and any rows that depend on it, respecting all foreign key constraints.
Properly handle self-referencing tables by deleting child rows before parent rows. This is possibly where things venture into scary territory.
Operate within a single transaction.

Example Scenario:
Consider this hyper-simplified representation of the database I'm working with.

Expectations:
Given this hierarchy, if I attempt to delete a Folder, the procedure should recursively delete all dependent ElementInstances, Elements, Pages, Forms, and child Folders (in that order).
Questions:

Is it feasible to implement a stored procedure to handle this kind of dynamic cascading delete operation for temporal tables?
How can I efficiently handle recursive deletions, especially with self-referencing tables, without running into recursion depth issues?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Your "database representation" shows several tables but does not say which one is a temporal table ... or do you mean they are all temporal tables? Also since temporal tables do track deletions (in the history tables) and you say you don't want to touch the history tables, it is not clear what is the problem with deletions here. But generally speaking if you are "rolling your own cascade delete" then you work from the bottom up - all ElementInstances related to any element or page related to any Form related to the Folder you are deleting, then the Elements and Pages, then the Forms ...

... so ... I'm not sure that I see any recursion here to worry about ...

Doing this dynamically as you request is going to be a nightmare. SQL is not well suited to dynamic operation, its intended to be static. If it were me I would write a delete SP per table that can have a row deleted from it that needs to follow this approach - thats the normal way to do it. It would be possible to write a SP with dynamic SQL which looks up the existing relationships etc etc, but that would a massive job, not something we can help you with, and a nightmare to test and maintain, and I would suggest be a huge risk for your organisation because of the potential for it to break.

All recursion can be written as a loop, just that it gets messier. Pretty sure someone already written this though, just look around. But is your idea to have FK's removed? Or just change so they don't cascade?

@topsail The idea was to assume they're all temporal. Or, simply, to assume ON CASCADE DELETE doesn't work (as is a limitation of temporal tables). The problem with deletions in this case is that they aren't easy to perform because of that limitation. I am just trying to mimic the behaviour of a cascading delete. My real database has roughly 10 temporal tables, and I wanted to avoid writing a deletion procedure for each.

@DaleK Thanks, this is the advice I was looking for. If it goes against the grain, I won't implement it. As for writing an SP for each table... in my real scenario I have maybe 10 temporal tables that follow a relationship like A has B, B has C, C has D, and so on. In table A's deletion SP, I'm assuming I'd need to perform deletes for D, C, then B, correct? For B, I'd have to delete D and C. It just seems very redundant... Sounds like a good case for a trigger, but they also do not work for temporal tables.

Triggers will work just fine on temporal tables. You just have to use an AFTER trigger. It is actually stated as such in the documentation you linked in your question. For your example I would create for each level instead of trying to do it all in one.

@DaleK My brain is mush, I realize I can just call the other stored procs in sequence. Ends up being a fairly clean solution.

@SeanLange This won't work if I have FK constraints though... correct? E.g., if I delete a Form, the AFTER trigger will fire after the deletion was attempted, which would end up in a FK constraint error. If INSTEAD OF worked here this wouldn't be a problem. Unless I'm overthinking.

It can be done but is kind of painful. If you post your sample tables as create statements I can work something up.

@SeanLange I took another stab at triggers and it was indeed very painful. I opted for individual delete procedures for each table and posted an answer.

I decided to write a deletion procedure for each table. Below is an example from the application I'm building, and isn't 1:1 with the example given in my OP, but it follows the same principles.

Omitting many tables for the sake of brevity, assume all temporal.
Here's the procedure to delete the top-level entity, which has a self reference. It'll first locate all of it's child Folders and execute the DeleteFolder procedure on it to begin a sort of recursive process, then it'll delete the Forms belonging to them via the DeleteForm procedure.
DeleteFolder.sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteFolder]
    @FolderId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Delete child folders
    DECLARE @ChildFolderId INT;
    DECLARE ChildFoldersCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Id] FROM [ui].[Folders] WHERE [ParentId] = @FolderId;

    OPEN ChildFoldersCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM ChildFoldersCursor INTO @ChildFolderId;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC [dbo].[DeleteFolder] @ChildFolderId;
        FETCH NEXT FROM ChildFoldersCursor INTO @ChildFolderId;
    END

    CLOSE ChildFoldersCursor;
    DEALLOCATE ChildFoldersCursor;

    -- Delete related forms
    DECLARE @FormId INT;
    DECLARE FormsCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Id] FROM [config].[Forms] WHERE [FolderId] = @FolderId;

    OPEN FormsCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM FormsCursor INTO @FormId;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC [dbo].[DeleteForm] @FormId;
        FETCH NEXT FROM FormsCursor INTO @FormId;
    END

    CLOSE FormsCursor;
    DEALLOCATE FormsCursor;

    -- Delete the folder
    DELETE FROM [ui].[Folders] WHERE [Id] = @FolderId;
END

Here's the procedure that is called in the previous one. It details how to delete the entities that depend on the given Form. Again, it continues to use stored procedures for deletions instead of explicit row deletions.
DeleteForm.sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteForm]
    @FormId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Delete related pages
    DECLARE @PageId INT;
    DECLARE PagesCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Id] FROM [ui].[Pages] WHERE [FormId] = @FormId;

    OPEN PagesCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM PagesCursor INTO @PageId;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC [dbo].[DeletePage] @PageId;
        FETCH NEXT FROM PagesCursor INTO @PageId;
    END

    CLOSE PagesCursor;
    DEALLOCATE PagesCursor;

    -- Delete related lookup lists
    DECLARE @LookupListId INT;
    DECLARE LookupListsCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Id] FROM [config].[LookupLists] WHERE [FormId] = @FormId;

    OPEN LookupListsCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM LookupListsCursor INTO @LookupListId;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC [dbo].[DeleteLookupList] @LookupListId;
        FETCH NEXT FROM LookupListsCursor INTO @LookupListId;
    END

    CLOSE LookupListsCursor;
    DEALLOCATE LookupListsCursor;

    -- Delete the related Elements
    DECLARE @ElementId INT;
    DECLARE ElementsCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Id] FROM [config].[Elements] WHERE [FormId] = @FormId;

    OPEN ElementsCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM ElementsCursor INTO @ElementId;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC [dbo].[DeleteElement] @ElementId;
        FETCH NEXT FROM ElementsCursor INTO @ElementId;
    END

    CLOSE ElementsCursor;
    DEALLOCATE ElementsCursor;

    -- Delete the form
    DELETE FROM [config].[Forms] WHERE [Id] = @FormId;
END

Eventually, we get to a point where we're deleting leafs that don't depend on anything, and thus we've emulated ON DELETE CASCADE, with a bit more flexibility and (unfortunately) a lot more code.

Ouch why all the cursors? You should be able to delete the children without a cursor here. For example to delete elements you could instead delete using FormId instead of row by agonizing row.

@SeanLange As OP suggested, I am not very familiar with SQL, so I don't really know what is taboo/inefficient/etc. In my real project, Elements is temporal and has multiple tables that depend on it, so I can't just perform a normal delete because that will fail due to FK constraints; I must instead call its DeleteElement stored procedure. I'm not sure how else I'd do that without iterating. I know that wasn't clear from my post. Are you suggesting that for deleting Folders/Forms I should not be using cursors and calling the deletion procedures?

I am suggesting that you delete the set of rows you want to delete instead of row by row. If you need to delete 1,000 rows from a table it is far more efficient to delete them all at once instead of issuing 1,000 delete statements. Maybe in this case a second procedure to delete the group is needed instead of the existing procedure that deletes one row at a time?
